# How to share data across pages in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two pages. One is `login.html` and 2nd is `home.html`. When login is successful, it redirects to `home.html`. I want to access the id of the user in `home.html`.
So I have saved the id from the controller named "loginForm" (controller for `login.html`) through `setCurrentUser(id)` in the `services.js`.
And trying to access the id from controller named "expenseForm" (corresponding controller for `home.html`) through `getCurrentUser()`. But it is coming as empty string. Please guide me with this.

**controller.js -**

```
var expmodule = angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);

expmodule.controller('loginForm', function($scope, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.login = function (userid, password) {
        var users = sharedProperties.getUsersInfo();
        users.forEach(function (usr) {
            if (usr.id === userid && usr.pwd === password) {
                alert("Welcome " + userid);
                sharedProperties.setAuthentication();
                sharedProperties.setCurrentUser(usr.id);
                window.location = "home.html";
            }
        })();
        if(sharedProperties.isAuthenticated() === false) {
            alert("Invalid Login");
        }
    }
});

expmodule.controller('expenseForm', function($scope, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.submitExpense = function (expenseInfo) {
        var id;
        id = sharedProperties.getCurrentUser();
        sharedProperties.setExpenseInfo(id, expenseInfo);
        alert(sharedProperties.getExpenseInfo(id));
    }
});

loginForm.$inject = ['$scope', 'sharedProperties'];
expenseForm.$inject = ['$scope', 'sharedProperties'];
```

**services.js -**

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
.service('sharedProperties', function () {
    var users = [{id: "Neha", pwd: "Neha"}, {id: "Sneha", pwd: "Sneha"}],
    authentication = false,
    expenses = {},
    currentUser = "";
    return {
        getUsersInfo: function () {
            return users;
        },
        setUserInfo: function (usr) {
            users.push(usr);
            expenses[usr.id] = [];
        },
        setAuthentication: function (user)      { authentication = true;      },
        isAuthenticated: function ()            { return authentication;      },
        setCurrentUser: function (id)           { currentUser = id;           },
        getCurrentUser: function ()             { return currentUser;         },
        getExpenseInfo: function (id)           { return expenses[id];        },
        setExpenseInfo: function (id, expense)  { expenses[id].push(expense); }
    }
});
```

Comment: Just a security note: it seems like bad practice to push user IDs and passwords in a JS page, which any visitor to your website can trivially look at.

Comment: Well, you are not leveraging angularjs's single page application strengths at all, if you have separate entry html pages and redirect the browser directly to those files. You should look up how angularjs routing works: Using parameters to redirect to different content using only one entry-file, with no hard browser redirect. You can then more easily share variables via factories/services.

Answer (score 1):

You can't share the data across different "**pages**" in angularjs. You need to use any persistent storage for this. I would advice you to use sessions/cookies for this.

Write a service (AuthService) which abstracts the underlying storage (session/cookie/localstorage) and save the user object once the user logins in.

Comment: Just a little info on the side: Angular's **[`$cookieStore`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore)** and **[`$cookies`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)** services already provide an abstraction over session cookies.